# Как вернуть класс ребенка

Tags: c#

У меня есть общий класс

```
public class ClassParent {
  public static ClassParent get() {
    return new ClassParent();
  }
}
```

И есть дочерние классы, к примеру:

```
public class ClassChild : ClassParent {
  ... code
}
```

Как сделать так, что бы при вызове:

```
ClassChild.get();
```

Возвращался обьект типа ClassChild, а не ClassParent?

Comment: Зачем? Просто используйте конструктор

Comment: @АндрейNOP ну к примеру я использую конструктор, для данного примера, но что если мне понадобиться вернуть массив таких элементов? Я не спрашиваю как хорошо, я спрашиваю как реализовать.

Comment: Никак, `ClassChild.get();` это на самом деле вызов `ClassParent.get()`, вам даже студия на это намекнет выделив строчку сереньким. Но скорее всего вам это не нужно, опишите свою реальную задачу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел самое оптимальное решение моей задачи, если кому то понадобиться то вот пример:

```
public class ClassParent<T> where T : new() {
    static public T Get() {
        return new T();
    }
}

public class ClassChild : ClassParent<ClassChild> {
  ... Some code
}
```

Comment: Гм, но теперь нет возможности получить простой `ClassParent`. Собственно, похерена возможность создать коллекцию базовых классов и записывать в неё дочерние и т. п.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, вообще желание этого "статического полиморфизма" странно, т. к. фактически вызовы статических методов разрешаются во время компиляции, а не во время исполнения, как в настоящем полиморфизме...

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov мне нужен был общи родитель, так сказать для сбора общих функций, сам родитель мне не нужен, как отдельный элемент

Comment: Ясно, понятно..